# What can cause a variable to be present in linker map file but not ELF symbol table?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

A variable is declared as

```
volatile bool is_usage_mode_convenience_activated = true;
```

It shows up in the linker map file with proper address but I cannot find it in the ELF symbol table (examined with readelf -s).

The dwarf debug info (readelf --debug-dump=info) is as follows

```
<2><42019>: Abbrev Number: 104 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <4201a>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x433aa): is_usage_mode_convenience_activated
    <4201e>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 3
    <4201f>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 21
    <42020>   DW_AT_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x49717): _ZN20vehiclemodesprovider35is_usage_mode_convenience_activatedE
    <42024>   DW_AT_type        : <0x392a3>
    <42028>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <42028>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
```

I expected a to find a DW_AT_location instead of DW_AT_declaration. There is no extern declaration for this variable in the program so the DW_TAG_variable does indeed describe the one and only declaration of the variable.

What circumstances can cause this? There is nothing strange with the variable declaration.

Comment: Does gdb see it?

Comment: What about `readelf -s` or `readelf -a`?

Comment: It's a member variable of your `vehiclemodesprovider` class, right?

Comment: I removed [tag:c] since this is not a C program; the tag is misleading.

Comment: @CraigEstey Doesn't see it, that was what I mean by symbol table examined by readelf, have clarified that in the post.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb Nope, vehiclemodesprovider is a namespace and the variable is "global" within this namespace.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, actually it does. Can print the value. And how it does that is beyond my understanding. It's almost like gdb interprets the elf file differently than readelf.

Comment: So, namespace-level definitions have external linkage. If it doesn't sow up in your ELF symbol file, is it at least in the GOT?

Answer (score 1):

It actually was in the symbol table but since readelf only writes the n first chars grep missed it. Using a different tool which showed the entire symbol revealed that it did exist in the symbol table. Still strange though that it didn't have a location attribute.